# Speeding up a dependent loop

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, vectorization

I will use this simple made-up, self-contained function, which is supposed to get as inputs: the initial position, force, time step and number of iterations; and return as outputs: the time and position vectors.

```
function [time,pos] = example(pos0, force, N, dt) 

clc;

pos = zeros(N+1,3);
vel = zeros(N,3);
pos(1,:)=pos0;


for i = 1:N

        time(i+1) = i*dt;

        % solver finds the velocities given forces and previous positions
        vel(i,:) = force./(norm(pos(i,:)+1));

        % evolution calculates new positions using new velocities
        pos(i+1,:) = pos(i,:) + vel(i,:)*dt;

end

end
```

How could I speed the for loop up, given that parallel computation is not an option (the loop entries depend on the previous iteration)? Would vectorising be an option? How would I go about it?

Comment: Are you intentionally working in 3 dimensions?

Comment: Also, it seems that you're trying to model the equation Force = velocity*|position|, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I am intentionally working in 3D. And the Force=vel*|pos| is clearly nonsense, but I chose that just as a code example which does only involve simple operations and few variables.

Comment: Well, you can vectorize the time variable by doing something like `time=tl:dt:th` where `tl` and `th` are your lower and upper time limits. Your last line becomes `pos(i+1,:)=pos(i,:)+vel(i,:)*time(i);` . Since your position and velocity depend on each other as you go through time, I don't see how you can vectorize that.

Comment: @HS-nebula The last line should still use `dt` (this never changes), but of course, `time` can be calculated as you suggested

Comment: @usumdelphini: If you want to numerically solve a differential equation, you have little chance to parallelize or vectorize it. Maybe post the actual equation to see if there is a closed-form solution (and maybe post that on [math.se]).

Comment: @chtz Good catch! Totally missed that.